# How to visualize pointwise convergence of sequences of functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence

i understand how to geometrically interpret the uniformly convergence of function sequences. 
[image]

But what does pointwise convergence mean? Can you give an example or a visualization? I am using this definition:

$\forall \varepsilon >0 \, \forall x\in D \, \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \, \forall n>N : |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Pointwise convergence means $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x$. So pick any vertical line $x=a$, and watch $f_n(a)\to f(a)$ along that line. It's just convergence, but not uniform...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeating what @runway44 said but with a bit more about the visualization.

At any vertical line $x = a$, you'll seen that $f_n(a) \rightarrow f(a)$ along that line.

*In terms of the picture you provided*: if $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ pointwise but not uniformly then for any given $\epsilon$ there will be parts of $f_n$ that go outside the $\pm \epsilon$ envelope. If you focus on a portion where $f_n$ is outside and make $n$ even bigger then eventually that portion will go inside the $\pm \epsilon$ envelope, but there will still be another portion that isn't contained.